# Shortcut to Open Folder in New Window with AHK

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, window, files-folders

**The problem**: in Windows 10, at least version 1809, there is no shortcut to open a selected folder in a new window. Some say they can do it with ctrl-double click or ctrl-enter. None of this, however, worked for me, nor do Microsoft's shortcut guides report this ability.

**The solution**: through trial and error, I discovered that the only combination that opens a selected folder in another window is ctrl-middleclick. So I want to use Autohotkey to remap this shortcut to the combination it should naturally be: crtl-enter.

**The unexpected**: ctrl-middleclick, however, only works when the cursor is over selected folder.

**The question**: how to use AHK to automatically direct the cursor over a selected (not open) folder if the cursor is in another part of the screen, so that I can then use ctrl-middleclick?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AutoHotKey (V1) script will use Ctrl+Enter in Explorer
in order to open the currently selected folder or folders
with no need for moving the cursor:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
^enter::
For each, file in getSelected()
 Run, explorer.exe "%file%"
Return
#IfWinActive

getSelected() { ; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=17&t=60403#p255256 by teadrinker
 hwnd := WinExist("A"), selection := []
 WinGetClass, class
 If (class ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass")
  For window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
   If (window.hwnd = hwnd)
    For item in window.document.SelectedItems
     selection.Push(item.Path)
 Return selection
}
```

Comment: It's not yet a solution for how to move the cursor over a previously selected item, and I think it would be useful in the future. But it is a solution to the central problem. In fact, it is better than the solution I suggested, as it can handle several folders at the same time. Thanks.